# How to get Host name when running Angular with SSR. @angular/ssr not Universal

Tags: angular, firebase, server-side-rendering, firebase-hosting, angular-ssr

I am using Angular v17*

I have multiple Firebase hostings attached to the same Firebase project.
All of them use SSR (@angular/ssr) and now I want to get the HOST name so I can query to server and fetch some specific theme for individual hosting.

test1.com uses a Blue/Green theme
test2.com uses a Yellow/Red theme

So I want to get the host name and fetch the style configurations from a database.

Using

```
   @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
```

Or

```
private platformLocation: PlatformLocation,
```

Is not helpful and it's only working on the client side...

Also I tried to add Injection tokens in my server.ts file but again did not work

```
 commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
          { provide: 'request', useFactory: () => req, deps: [] },
          {
            provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: (req)
          },
          {
            provide: 'RESPONSE', useValue: (res)
          }
        ],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
```

And inside the component constructor I have

```
@Optional() @Inject('REQUEST') private req1: any,
@Optional() @Inject('request') private req2: any,
```

But again output is NULL.